does my Symfony 7.1 web application necessarily need doctrine-messenger?
I am working on a scheduling and billing system for a clinical psychology solo practice. The data persistence will be handled by Doctrine and mariadb. Evidently, the symfony/messenger component is installed by default, and when you install Doctrine evidently you also get Doctrine messenger. When I created my first migration, I got
$this->addSql('CREATE TABLE messenger_messages (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, body LONGTEXT NOT NULL, headers LONGTEXT NOT NULL, queue_name VARCHAR(190) NOT NULL, created_at DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT \'(DC2Type:datetime_immutable)\', available_at DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT \'(DC2Type:datetime_immutable)\', delivered_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL COMMENT \'(DC2Type:datetime_immutable)\', INDEX IDX_75EA56E0FB7336F0 (queue_name), INDEX IDX_75EA56E0E3BD61CE (available_at), INDEX IDX_75EA56E016BA31DB (delivered_at), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB');

in my up() method, though I didn't explicitly ask for it. Uncertain what to do, I've commented it out. Next migration, same thing. So I am wondering if I should remove the doctrine-messenger component, and if so, how to do it safely. Or leave it alone and let the possibly unnecessary table be created? As it stands, I don't forsee a need for a message bus.
What do you think?

You should be able to safely remove any package that is directly listed in  you composer.json except symfony core and not a third party dependency but make sure to remove the related config files too. Then everything should work. Depending on what type of project template you use there are different dependencies that come with them but are not required.
